# python-docstring-fill does not align properly

Tags: python, wrapping, doc-strings

I am using `python-docstring-fill` (function of https://github.com/glyph/python-docstring-mode) to wrap Python docstrings. I observe that it does not align based the Python-way. It should be as:

```
"""Do this

Exaplain...
Exaplain...
"""
```

---

Example (the correct way):

```
def sacct_result(self):
    """Return sacct output for the job.

    Do this...
    Do that...
    """
```

`M-q` `(python-docstring-fill)` converts into, where it adds spaces before closing `"""`:

```
def sacct_result(self):
    """Return sacct output for the job.

      Do this...  Do that...
        """
```

How can I prevent this wrong wrapping from happening? or just disable wrapping in the docstrings since it does it wrongly.

Could be related to:
[In emacs Python mode, how do I set a different auto-fill width for docstrings and code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8823924/2402577)

Comment: have you read the open issue that describes and solves this exact problem? https://github.com/glyph/python-docstring-mode/issues/30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@nega` refers following issue solves the problem I was having: [Broken formatting with new python.el (0.28)](https://github.com/glyph/python-docstring-mode/issues/30).

The [Fix](https://github.com/glyph/python-docstring-mode/pull/31) and the patch that solves it could be seen here: https://github.com/glyph/python-docstring-mode/commit/0dbc133cc9f207a448e59f3849c5e3ca51da7bd6.